# Mutate while accessing value in list column in a pipe with map and pluck

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, pipe, purrr

I would like to achieve the following:

- filter dataframe **catalogs** based on multiple columns in dataframe **orders**, for each row in dataframe **orders** and store the result in a list column in dataframe **orders**.  (succeeded)
- calculate the difference between a date in data frame **orders** and another date in the new listcolumn.

Table `s_orders` contains order data for different people (account keys). Table `s_catalogs` contains all catalogs that were sent to each account key

For each order, I want to know:

- if and what catalogs were sent from the previous order (or the beginning) until the day before the focal order.  More specifically, consumers received a (paper) catalog at `s_catalogs$CATDATE`. I want to know for each order what catalogs were received between the previous order (`s_orders$PREVORDER`) and the latest order. Because some consumers do not have a previous order I set the previous order date *startdate* to date("1999-12-31") which is the beginning of my dataset.
- Then I want to do some calculations on the catalog data. (in this example: calculate the difference between date of a catalog and the order date)

For this, I have written a function **getCatalogs**, which takes the account key and two dates as input, and outputs a dataframe with the results from the other table. *Would be much appreciated if someone has a better, more efficient solution? maybe with some sort of join?*

I think my main problem is how to use mutate, pmap, pipes, pluck interchangeably for building complex queries on multiple tables.

My actual problem is outlined in sections **Desired result** and **Problem**.

```
# packages needed
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")
library("purrr")
#library("tidyverse")
```

## Example data

( i sampled some users from my data. s_ stands for 'sample')

```
# orders
s_orders <- structure(list(ACCNTKEY = c(2806, 2806, 2806, 3729, 3729, 3729, 
3729, 4607, 4607, 4607, 4607, 4742, 11040, 11040, 11040, 11040, 
11040, 17384), ORDDATE = structure(c(11325, 11703, 11709, 11330, 
11375, 11384, 12153, 11332, 11445, 11589, 11713, 11333, 11353, 
11429, 11662, 11868, 11960, 11382), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))

# # A tibble: 18 x 2
#    ACCNTKEY ORDDATE   
#       <dbl> <date>    
#  1     2806 2001-01-03
#  2     2806 2002-01-16
#  3     2806 2002-01-22
#  4     3729 2001-01-08
#  5     3729 2001-02-22
#  6     3729 2001-03-03
#  7     3729 2003-04-11
#  8     4607 2001-01-10
#  9     4607 2001-05-03
# 10     4607 2001-09-24
# 11     4607 2002-01-26
# 12     4742 2001-01-11
# 13    11040 2001-01-31
# 14    11040 2001-04-17
# 15    11040 2001-12-06
# 16    11040 2002-06-30
# 17    11040 2002-09-30
# 18    17384 2001-03-01
```

```
# catalogs
s_catalogs <- structure(list(ACCNTKEY = c("2806", "2806", "4607", "2806", "4607", 
"4607", "4607"), CATDATE = structure(c(11480, 11494, 11522, 11858, 
11886, 12264, 12250), class = "Date"), CODE = c("2806/07/2001", 
"2806/21/2001", "4607/19/2001", "2806/20/2002", "4607/18/2002", 
"4607/31/2003", "4607/17/2003")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   ACCNTKEY CATDATE    CODE        
#   <chr>    <date>     <chr>       
# 1 2806     2001-06-07 2806/07/2001
# 2 2806     2001-06-21 2806/21/2001
# 3 4607     2001-07-19 4607/19/2001
# 4 2806     2002-06-20 2806/20/2002
# 5 4607     2002-07-18 4607/18/2002
# 6 4607     2003-07-31 4607/31/2003
# 7 4607     2003-07-17 4607/17/2003
```

## calculate the lagged order date

```
# calculate previous order date for each order in s_orders
s_orders<-s_orders %>%
  group_by(ACCNTKEY) %>%
  arrange(ORDDATE) %>%
  mutate(PREVORDER=as_date(lag(ORDDATE)))
```

So now we know the previous order (if any)

## Function getCatalogs (improvement appreciated)

So the below function getCatalogs returns a dataframe with the catalogs that were received by that account key before the order (or actually in between the last orders/catalogs that were received between *startdate* and *enddate*).

```
# in case _startdate_ is missing then I set it to some starting value

getCatalogs<-function(key,startdate,enddate){

  if(is.na(startdate)){
    startdate<-as_date(date("1999-12-31")) 
  }
  tmp <- s_catalogs[s_catalogs$ACCNTKEY==key &
                    s_catalogs$CATDATE<enddate &
                    s_catalogs$CATDATE>=startdate,]

  if (NROW(tmp)>0){
    return(tmp)
  }else{return(NA)}
}
```

## Use the function

**let's get for each order all catalogs in a *listcolumn***

```
# For each row in s_orders search in dataframe s_catalogs all catalogs that were received for that account key before the order date but after the previous order. 

s_orders <- s_orders %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(catalogs = 
pmap(c(list(ACCNTKEY),list(PREVORDER),list(ORDDATE)),.f= function(x,y,z){getCatalogs(x,y,z)}))
```

This line for example gets the date of the latest catalog, **which is what i need**:

```
s_orders %>% pluck("catalogs") %>% pluck(13) %>% pluck("CATDATE") %>% max()

# [1] "2001-06-21"
```

## Desired result:

Now I would like to retrieve the number of days between the above date and the date of the order (ORDDATE). **The following code does it exactly but it is only correct in row 13.**

```
# get amount of days since last catalog
s_orders3 <- s_orders %>% 
mutate(diff = ORDDATE - s_orders %>% 
              pluck("catalogs") %>% pluck(13) %>% pluck("CATDATE") %>% max())

# # A tibble: 18 x 5
#    ACCNTKEY ORDDATE    PREVORDER  catalogs         diff     
#       <dbl> <date>     <date>     <list>           <time>   
#  1     2806 2001-01-03 NA         <lgl [1]>        -169 days
#  2     3729 2001-01-08 NA         <lgl [1]>        -164 days
#  3     4607 2001-01-10 NA         <lgl [1]>        -162 days
#  4     4742 2001-01-11 NA         <lgl [1]>        -161 days
#  5    11040 2001-01-31 NA         <lgl [1]>        -141 days
#  6     3729 2001-02-22 2001-01-08 <lgl [1]>        -119 days
#  7    17384 2001-03-01 NA         <lgl [1]>        -112 days
#  8     3729 2001-03-03 2001-02-22 <lgl [1]>        -110 days
#  9    11040 2001-04-17 2001-01-31 <lgl [1]>         -65 days
# 10     4607 2001-05-03 2001-01-10 <lgl [1]>         -49 days
# 11     4607 2001-09-24 2001-05-03 <tibble [1 × 3]>   95 days
# 12    11040 2001-12-06 2001-04-17 <lgl [1]>         168 days
# 13     2806 2002-01-16 2001-01-03 <tibble [2 × 3]>  209 days
# 14     2806 2002-01-22 2002-01-16 <lgl [1]>         215 days
# 15     4607 2002-01-26 2001-09-24 <lgl [1]>         219 days
# 16    11040 2002-06-30 2001-12-06 <lgl [1]>         374 days
# 17    11040 2002-09-30 2002-06-30 <lgl [1]>         466 days
# 18     3729 2003-04-11 2001-03-03 <lgl [1]>         659 days
```

Check manually:

```
date("2002-01-16")-date("2001-06-21")
# Time difference of 209 days
```

## Problem

However, the code subtracts the same date from order date in every row. I want it to use the date that belongs to each particular row.

So the problem is how to replace the `%>% pluck(13) %>%` by some command that dows this trick to every row and put it in the diff column.

I am really searching for a solution that uses either purrr or dplyr or some other package that is just as efficient and clear.

Comment: I appreciate the amount of work you've put into solving the problem, but it's probably easier for us to help (and possibly for you to debug) if you can either isolate the problems you're having, maybe into separate questions, or pare this down to just the essential part of what's going wrong. See the _minimal_ part of [mcve]

Comment: @camille tnx for your feedback! The minimal problem is in de section "desired result" and "problem". You will need everything above that. Of course, I can delete everything in section "I tried". Yet those failed attempts may provide guidance for the answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?: "if and what catalogs were sent from the previous order (or the beginning) until the day before the focal order"

Comment: Dear @VitaliAvagyan, I just updated the post with some elaboration on that point. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you for an edit, @Dr.T. , I will give it a shot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that I have understood the question clearly, here is my attempt trying to solve the problem. I changed the `getCatalogs` function to return only `max` `CATDATE` in case if it is present.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

getCatalogs<-function(key,startdate,enddate){
    if(is.na(startdate))  startdate<- as.Date("1999-12-31")
    tmp <- s_catalogs$CATDATE[s_catalogs$ACCNTKEY==key &
                              s_catalogs$CATDATE<enddate &
                              s_catalogs$CATDATE>=startdate]

    if (length(tmp) > 0) max(tmp) else NA
}


s1_orders<- s_orders %>%
               group_by(ACCNTKEY) %>%
               arrange(ORDDATE) %>%
               mutate(PREVORDER=lag(ORDDATE))
```

and then use `pmap` like :

```
s1_orders %>% 
  mutate(catalogs = pmap_dbl(list(ACCNTKEY,PREVORDER,ORDDATE), getCatalogs), 
         catalogs = as.Date(catalogs, origin = "1970-01-01"), 
         diff = ORDDATE - catalogs)

#   ACCNTKEY ORDDATE    PREVORDER  catalogs   diff    
#      <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <drtn>  
# 1     2806 2001-01-03 NA         NA          NA days
# 2     3729 2001-01-08 NA         NA          NA days
# 3     4607 2001-01-10 NA         NA          NA days
# 4     4742 2001-01-11 NA         NA          NA days
# 5    11040 2001-01-31 NA         NA          NA days
# 6     3729 2001-02-22 2001-01-08 NA          NA days
# 7    17384 2001-03-01 NA         NA          NA days
# 8     3729 2001-03-03 2001-02-22 NA          NA days
# 9    11040 2001-04-17 2001-01-31 NA          NA days
#10     4607 2001-05-03 2001-01-10 NA          NA days
#11     4607 2001-09-24 2001-05-03 2001-07-19  67 days
#12    11040 2001-12-06 2001-04-17 NA          NA days
#13     2806 2002-01-16 2001-01-03 2001-06-21 209 days
#14     2806 2002-01-22 2002-01-16 NA          NA days
#15     4607 2002-01-26 2001-09-24 NA          NA days
#16    11040 2002-06-30 2001-12-06 NA          NA days
#17    11040 2002-09-30 2002-06-30 NA          NA days
#18     3729 2003-04-11 2001-03-03 NA          NA days
```

---

**Update**

Without changing the current `getCatalogs` function, we can test the `length` of `catalogs`

```
s1_orders %>% 
  mutate(catalogs = pmap(list(ACCNTKEY,PREVORDER,ORDDATE), getCatalogs),
         temp =  map_dbl(catalogs, ~if (length(.x) > 1)
                   .x %>% pluck("CATDATE") %>% max else NA), 
         temp = as.Date(temp, origin = "1970-01-01"),
         diff = ORDDATE - temp)
```

Comment: Dear @Ronak Shah, thanks for your effort! This however only partially solves the problem. There is a specific reason why I use a list column. I have in fact >45k orders and >800k catalogs that were sent. When I store the catalogs per order in a listcolumn i will have to go through that operation only once, after which I can save the dataset. Therefore, I am specifically looking for a solution that extracts the data from the listcolumn such I can do multiple calculations on the same selection of catalogs without having to run the `getCatalogs` query again.

Comment: @Dr.T. I have updated the answer where it extracts the data from the listcolumn. See the **update** part of the answer.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for your help! your query makes more sense! 

(first calculate the intermediate columns, then compute the simple difference. I was working the other way around)

Comment: Ah sorry, I only checked the UP arrow. it's my first question so as u can infer from the comments I have to get acquainted with Stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah..I saw that this is your first question here. :)